# SocialSharing PhoneGap Plugin do not share URL parameters on FB wall

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
 var url = 'http://myweb.com?name=shareGroup&invitekey='+key+'&grpId='+grpId;

 window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Hey there! download this app, its amazing.', null, null,url, function(){

            alert("LINK: "+url);

   },function(){});
```

Here `url` parameters is not sharing on FB. On FB wall when i click the shared link it redirect to `http://myweb.com` rather than `http://myweb.com?name=shareGroup&invitekey=XXX&grpId=YYY`. Here inside alert it shows correct `url`.

I have tried with encoding url using `encodeURI` but same result.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779784/adding-social-share-links-to-phonegap-app/26782026#26782026

Comment: Maybe your page has the canonical URL or `og:url` value set to `http://myweb.com`, even on those pages with parameters? If so, Facebook will only consider the former the “real” URL of the Open Graph object. Use the debug tool to find out what data exactly Facebook sees for your URL(s), https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug