# How to add social sharing button in phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I am new to `phonegap`, I am creating a wishes/greeting app.I want to add a social button to share that greeting to people. The selected greeting should be share by Twitter, g+, WhatsApp and Facebook.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779784/adding-social-share-links-to-phonegap-app/26782026#26782026

Answer (score 5):

**PhoneGap Social Sharing plugin for Android, iOS and Windows Phone:**

I propose you to use the following plugin to add social sharing option. Its pretty simple and straight forward to use.

[Social sharing link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

**Installation**

Automatically (CLI / Plugman):
SocialSharing is compatible with Cordova Plugman, compatible with PhoneGap 3.0 CLI, here's how it works with the CLI:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

or with Cordova CLI, from npm:

```
 $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
 $ cordova prepare
```

SocialSharing.js is brought in automatically. There is no need to change or add anything in your html.

**Manually**

1. Add the following xml to all the config.xml files you can find:

   ```
   <!-- for iOS -->
   <feature name="SocialSharing">
   <param name="ios-package" value="SocialSharing" />
   </feature>

   <!-- for Android (you will find one in res/xml) -->
   <feature name="SocialSharing">
   <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
   </feature>

   <!-- for Windows Phone -->
   <feature name="SocialSharing">
   <param name="wp-package" value="SocialSharing"/>
   </feature>
   ```

For sharing remote images (or other files) on Android, the file needs to be stored locally first, so add this permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For iOS, you'll need to add the Social.framework and MessageUI.framework to your project. Click your project, Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries, search for and add Social.framework and MessageUI.framework.

2. Grab a copy of SocialSharing.js, add it to your project and reference it in index.html:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
   ```
3. Download the source files for iOS and/or Android and copy them to your project.

iOS: Copy SocialSharing.h and SocialSharing.m to                                              platforms/ios//Plugins

Android: Copy SocialSharing.java to platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins (create the folders)

Window Phone: Copy SocialSharing.cs to platforms/wp8/Plugins/nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing (create the folders)

**PhoneGap Build**

Just add the following xml to your config.xml to always use the latest version of this plugin (which is published to plugins.cordova.io these days):

```
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
```

or to use an older version, hosted at phonegap build:

```
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.16" />
```

SocialSharing.js is brought in automatically. Make sure though you include a reference to cordova.js in your index.html's head:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

**Using the share sheet**

Here are some examples you can copy-paste to test the various combinations:

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message only')">message only</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message and subject', 'The subject')">message and subject</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, null, 'http://www.x-services.nl')">link only</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message and link', null, null, 'http://www.x-services.nl')">message and link</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', null)">image only</button>

// Beware: passing a base64 file as 'data:' is not supported on Android 2.x: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901#c43
// Hint: when sharing a base64 encoded file on Android you can set the filename by passing it as the subject (second param)
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, 'Android filename', 'data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMALMBAP8AAP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAUKAAEALAAAAAAMAAwAQAQZMMhJK7iY4p3nlZ8XgmNlnibXdVqolmhcRQA7', null)">base64 image only</button>

// Hint: you can share multiple files by using an array as thirds param: ['file 1','file 2', ..], but beware of this Android Kitkat Facebook issue: [#164]
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message and image', null, 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', null)">message and image</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message, image and link', null, 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 'http://www.x-services.nl')">message, image and link</button>

<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message, subject, image and link', 'The subject', 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 'http://www.x-services.nl')">message, subject, image and link</button>
```

**Sharing directly to..**

## Facebook

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('Message via Facebook', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">msg via Facebook (with errcallback)</button>
```

## Twitter

```
<!-- unlike most apps Twitter doesn't like it when you use an array to pass multiple files as the second param -->
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message via Twitter')">message via Twitter</button>
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message and link via Twitter', null /* img */, 'http://www.x-services.nl')">msg and link via Twitter</button>
```

## WhatsApp

- Note that on iOS when sharing an image and text, only the image is shared - let's hope WhatsApp creates a proper iOS extension to fix this.
- Before using this method you may want to use canShareVia('whatsapp'.. (see below).

  ```
  <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)})">msg via WhatsApp (with errcallback)</button>
  ```

If you want to know more please check the link..[Social Sharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#manually)

If the answer helps you please Vote up. Cheers

Comment: Whenever i click on share button nothing is happened.  In LogCat  This Msg show    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined.

Comment: Which version of cordova you are using?

Comment: Did you add "<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />" in the config.xml file

Comment: AM using cordova 2.3.0.. <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />  give error  Error:-undefined prefix:gap .thats why I did not include it.

Comment: Did you Copy SocialSharing.java to platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins (create the folders)

Comment: add the screen shots of your config.xml and android manifest.xml files

Comment: My manifest file has following permissions...  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I think you are missing something in your side. If you want I can check your coding part. my mail address is cbasak059@gmail.com, send the code in a zip file. Otherwise send me yours I will make a demo app and give that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it not using phonegap, but rather create platform version (for example: android) and then run it in Android Studio via your phone. I tried simulator but didn't work there as there is no WhatsApp or other social app in the simulator, that is why it will show you nothing.